# Parsing a data in excel using transpose and group_split

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tibble

I am trying to turn this dataset

```
structure(list(X1 = c("A1", "One", "B1", "One", "B2", "A2", 
"One", "B3", "One", "B4", "One", "B5", "One", "A3", "B6", 
"One", "B7", "One", "B8"), X2 = c("NA", "Two", "NA", "Two", 
"NA", "NA", "Two", "NA", "Two", "NA", "Two", "NA", "Two", 
"NA", "NA", "Two", "NA", "Two", "NA"), X3 = c("NA", "Three", 
"NA", "Three", "NA", "NA", "Three", "NA", "Three", 
"NA", "Three", "NA", "Three", "NA", "NA", "Three", 
"NA", "Three", "NA")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-19L))
```

Into this dataset

```
structure(list(X1 = c("One", "One", "One", "One", "One", "One", "One", "One"),
X2 = c("Two", "Two", "Two", "Two", "Two", "Two", "Two", "Two"),
X3 = c("Three", "Three", "Three", "Three", "Three", "Three", "Three", "Three"),
X4 = c("B1", "B2", "B3", "B4","B5", "B6", "B7", "B8"),
X5 = c("A1", "A1", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A3", "A3", "A3")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

I have made some headway with the help of others. Mainly I can separate the dataset using

```
data %>% 
  group_by(split_on = cumsum(is.na(X2) & is.na(lag(X2)))) %>% 
  group_split(.keep = F) %>%
  `names<-`({.} %>% 
   map(~ .[1,1])%>% 
   unlist())
```

and then transpose the A row to a column using

```
replace(df, 1, df[1,1])[-1,]
```

or

```
df[,1] <- df[1,1]
df[-1,]
```

Where I am having trouble is putting these steps all together and putting the dataset back together.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: what is `Company`?

Comment: @Sirius updated

Comment: Why you are creating NA as `"NA"`

Answer (score 1):

The conditions are not very clear.  Here is a way to get the 'A' string and 'B' string from the data to create two new columns

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
data %>%
   type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>%
   group_by(grp = cumsum(str_detect(X1, 'A\\d+'))) %>% 
   mutate(X5 = first(X1),
     X4 = case_when(str_detect(X1, 'B\\d+')~ X1)) %>%
  fill(X4, .direction = 'updown') %>% 
  ungroup %>%
  na.omit %>%
  select(-grp)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 8 x 5
  X1    X2    X3    X5    X4   
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 One   Two   Three A1    B1   
2 One   Two   Three A1    B2   
3 One   Two   Three A2    B3   
4 One   Two   Three A2    B4   
5 One   Two   Three A2    B5   
6 One   Two   Three A2    B5   
7 One   Two   Three A3    B7   
8 One   Two   Three A3    B8
```